# How can I set default_url_options per mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

In Rails 5, we have two mailers for some business reason.

Let's call them `FooMailer` and `BarMailer`.

The business requirement is to set up the `default_url_options` **for each of them separately**:

- For `FooMailer` they should be `{ host: "wut.example.com" }`
- For `BarMailer` they should be `{ host: "blah.example.com" }`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For all mailers globally:

In `config/environment/production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://abc.co.uk' }
```

## Per mailer:

For Rails 5.0.x, setting up the `default_url_options` as method on each mailer seems to be working:

```
class FooMailer < ApplicationMailer
  ...
  def default_url_options
    { host: "wut.example.com" }
  end
  ...
end
```

and

```
class BarMailer < ApplicationMailer
  ...
  def default_url_options
    { host: "blah.example.com" }
  end
  ...
end
```

**A tip**: if you want to still set up those options in environment-specific files (like you do with global defaults) you can use the `Rails.applicaiton.config.x` for that:

```
class FooMailer < ApplicationMailer
  ...
  def default_url_options
    Rails.application.config.x.default_foo_mailer_url_options ||
      raise('No x.default_foo_mailer_url_options config found')
  end
  ...
end
```

and then in `config/environments/*.rb` you can set it up like this:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.x.default_foo_mailer_url_options = { 
    host: "wut.example.com" 
  }
  ...
end
```

Comment: This will not set it up **per mailer**, only globally.

Comment: @IvanKolmychek in production.rb works for all mailers

Comment: if you want, feel free to just copy-past stuff from my answer completely, add the stuff about global setup on top and I'll accept it and remove mine.